Toyota teams up with Pepco for Vehicle to Grid technology
I just read this news that Toyota is teaming up with Pepco to research the battery electric vehicles (BEV) with their Toyota bZ4X vehicle. The article states that the vehicles battery sends power back tot the grid. How and why on earth a EV car would want to send electricity back to grid, does it mean it generates electricity? Does it us solar panels are any other means of power generation? Here it the link to the article.

A battery electric vehicle is charged from the grid or other sources of electricity. For example, our house is grid-tied with our solar PV system and we charge two BEVs. It is not easily determined if the power is grid only or grid/PV combination, although it's certainly not PV only as the panels do not generate sufficient electricity to charge either vehicle fully and directly.
In the case of V2G, vehicle to grid, the electric vehicle service equipment (EVSE) remains connected to the vehicle by the stock cable, and when desired or required, allows the battery pack on the vehicle to send electricity to the grid. This could be useful in periods of peak power demand, reducing the requirement to spin up additional generation systems or to redirect power from other, perhaps more expensive sources.
There would be no solar involved unless the vehicle contained a series of solar panels contributing to the on-board storage. This is unlikely, as the areal requirement for any useful contribution is rather large.
One would hope that there would be suitable compensation to the vehicle owners for providing this resource. As an aside, the local power utility has reduced the net metering compensation provided to PV system owners to well below unity, making V2G a resource in which I would not participate, due to distrust of the utility.

I have proposed on more than one occasion that utilities should be required to pay fair market for battery storage-sourced power. I also think all govt. subsidies pertaining to GTPV should require an appropriate battery storage capacity. And of course everyone on both sides hates this idea because it is fair and good for everyone.
